# MySQL Delete from multiple tables in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables and I'm trying to run a multiple delete query that would delete all the products and tasks when deleting a repair record.
Note that the linking tables have `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraints.

Now the problem that I am having is that when I run this query it only deletes the `repair`, `taskRepair`, (1 task record but it has 3 in total), and the products associated with the deleted task.

```
DELETE bp, t, r
FROM repair AS r
LEFT JOIN taskRepair AS tr ON r.repairID = tr.repairID
INNER JOIN task AS t ON t.taskID = tr.taskID
LEFT JOIN boughtProductTask AS bpt ON bpt.taskID = t.taskID
INNER JOIN boughtProduct AS bp ON bp.boughtProductID = bpt.boughtProductID
WHERE r.repairID = ?
```

I did modify this to a `SELECT` Query changing `DELETE bp, t, r` to `SELECT *` and it did return all the records. So my question is what's wrong with this query?

[image: Database Tables]

Comment: I am guessing that the last `inner join` should be `left join`, because it turns earlier outer joins into inner joins.

Comment: @GordonLinoff same results as an { INNER JOIN }

Answer (score 1):

I believe in those cases, best practice is defining foreign key constraints on the tables with `ON DELETE CASCADE` option.

This way deleting the record from the parent table removes the records from child table, and you only need to deal with one as long as there's a relation.

---

If you are still looking to perform multiple deletes using a query, it seems to be possible, but not using a new-syntax join. From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html):

> You can specify multiple tables in a DELETE statement to delete rows from one or more tables depending on the particular condition in the WHERE clause. However, you cannot use ORDER BY or LIMIT in a multiple-table DELETE. The table_references clause lists the tables involved in the join. Its syntax is described in Section 12.2.8.1, “JOIN Syntax”.

The manual includes an example as well:

```
DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3
WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id;
```

I expect something along the lines of the following will work for you (I haven't the DB so I can't actually test the query):

```
DELETE bp, t, r
FROM repair AS r, taskRepair AS tr
INNER JOIN task AS t ON t.taskID = tr.taskID
LEFT JOIN boughtProductTask AS bpt ON bpt.taskID = t.taskID
INNER JOIN boughtProduct AS bp ON bp.boughtProductID = bpt.boughtProductID
WHERE r.repairID = tr.repairID AND r.repairID = ?
```

Edit - second suggestion:

```
DELETE bp, t, r
FROM repair AS r,
     task AS t,
     taskRepair AS tr,
     boughtProduct AS bp
LEFT JOIN boughtProductTask AS bpt ON bpt.taskID = t.taskID
WHERE r.repairID = tr.repairID
      AND t.taskID = tr.taskID
      AND bp.boughtProductID = bpt.boughtProductID
      AND r.repairID = ?
```

Note how I have changed the `JOIN` with `taskRepair` to another table in the `FROM` list, and added the condition all the way down inside the `WHERE` clause.

---

Sources:

- [MySQL Documentation: Foreign Key Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)
- [MySQL Documentation: Delete](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Comment: As for your first answer, the primary keys on my linking tables are also acting as a foreign key which has the ON DELETE CASCADE constraint on them. I was hoping that all I needed to do was delete the parent... I did test your query and it returned the same results as my query.. I'll try some modification with your query however, you have given me some ideas

Comment: Hey @Joseph118, I have added a second suggestion in the answer. let me know.

Comment: error... 'Unknown column 't.taskID' in 'on clause' '.. it's not making any sense to me

Comment: @Joseph118, try moving the `ON` condition to the `WHERE` clause. Totally removing the `ON`.

Comment: @Joseph118, replace the `DELETE` with `SELECT`, and try to figure why results are missing from the set. I'm starting to believe this has nothing to do with `DELETE` syntax.

Comment: I did that before and my logic was if you are able to select them all then you are able to delete them.. my test case has 9 records over all, select statement returns 9 records, while the delete statement only deletes 6 records. My other plan is to use commit syntax if this doesn't work