# MySQL - Delete record in several table

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, dml

I have many tables with same `versao` column. So, I would like DELETE using only one command in all tables, all records with especific 'version' column 'XYZ' value.

Some like that...

```
DELETE FROM `t1`, `t2`, `t3` WHERE `version` = 'XYZ';
```

But, didn't work.

Is there a way?

Tks a lot.

Comment: Here is better approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/32814592/1244597

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Delete from multiple tables in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814455/mysql-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-one-query)

Comment: MySQL has a [Multi-table `DELETE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html), but it does not really make sense here, since the tables do not have any relationship apart from having a column by the same name. I would still recommend running the `DELETE`s one by one. Else, you can also consider creating a stored procedure that uses dynamic SQL.

Comment: I think no... Both sound like table relationships. My case is simpler, I guess... (refer to comments 1 and 2)

Comment: Just I would like avoid: repeat same command several times. But if there's no way...